# How to render the DateField on a page in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, render

Hello I just started learning django and I am having problems rending the content the way I want to. Ideally I want to manage a system of tickets and have the ticket number, start-date, end-date and status appear on the page. Similar to the below format

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>test</h1>
    {% for cr in crs %}
        <p>{{ cr }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

From what I have in my views file the only thing being displayed when i view it in my web browser is only the ticket number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the content of your `cr_list.html` ?

Comment: edited to show the contents of my cr_list.html

Comment: There you have it: `<p>{{ cr }}</p>` will just contain `return self.cr_number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render the attributes `.start_date` and `.end_date` in your template as well, so:

```
{% for cr in crs %}
    {{ cr.cr_number }} {{ cf.start_date }} {{ cr.end_date }} {{ cr.get_status_display }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can specify the date format with the [**`|date`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{% for cr in crs %}
    {{ cr.cr_number }} {{ cf.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }} {{ cr.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }} {{ cr.get_status_display }}
{% endfor %}
```